# How to apply an integration function over a meshgrid

Tags: python, numpy, math

For simplicity's sake, let's say I have a function of the form:

[image: Equation link]

I would like to evaluate this function over an x-y mesh grid:

```
x = np.linspace(0,1,50)
y = np.linspace(0,1,50)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
```

where `xx` is used as the upper bound of integration (x_2), however I'm not sure of the best approach. I guess I'm looking for the right integration function that would allow me to do this. I know that this example could easily be solved analytically, and then executed over the entire meshgrid, but my real example is more complex and I would like to learn the appropriate numerical approach. I would really appreciate any suggestions. Thanks in advance!

I tried to use the quad function from scipy.integrate, but this only allows me to calculate one definite integral, not integrate over an entire meshgrid.

Comment: What does your integral limit mean? What is x₂?

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax" Kamermans, sorry that this was unclear, it will be all the values from 0-1 in array `x` that I used to make the meshgrid.

Comment: Yes, the integration bounds for `quad` have to be scalar.  So you can iterate and apply `quad` once for each pair of scalar bounds.

Comment: I don't know the best way to do this in python, but one way would be to sum the x integrals for all y values taking half the end point values (@y=0, y=1), and multiply by dy.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out! Using `@np.vectorize` I can initiate a function that accepts a meshgrid as an input:

```
# vectorize, to implement function over xy meshgrid
@np.vectorize

# define function
def z(x,y):
    
    # define function to be integrated
    def integrand(x):
         return x**3
        
    # integrate function
    ans,error = quad(integrand,0,x)

    # calculate full function, with integrated terms
    z = ans + y
    
    # return solution
    return(G)

# define meshgrid
x = np.linspace(0,1,50)
y = np.linspace(0,1,50)

XX, YY = np.meshgrid(T,P)

# implement function across meshgrid
z_out = z(XX,YY)
```

Thanks!